# Sharepoint 365 (online) set and get names in people picker field.

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I can't find any code that works on sharepoint 365. Is it posible to manipulate people picker field in sharepoint 365?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint-2013-use-the-57859f85 This sample code would help. This is a normal ASP.NET sharepoint application. This will help you implement people picker